# question regarding standard deviation and tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter-bootstrap-3, statistics

Using 0 as a baseline, I am looking to conduct a t-test. In fact, I want to perform a t-test on each of these 10 values. Here are the 10 values in list format. These 10 values correspond to standard deviation. However, I am not sure if I need more information than just the standard deviation to conduct the t-test.

```
list=[0.00330, 0.0022, 0.0018, 0.0016, 0.001, 0.0013, 0.0011, 0.00, 0.001, 0.0007]
```

So again, Before I  do anything code related,I need to know if more components are required to conduct these t-tests in the manner in which I describe above.
(These standard deviations were generated  through a bootstrapping process, if it helps anything to know)

Comment: _Before I do anything code related_: I believe you are looking for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). SO is a place for code helps, such as recommending you to use other name for `list` in order to avoid shadowing built-in functions

Comment: okay sounds good